# MySQL query: SELECT particular number of rows starting with today and go backwards

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL query I can't solve and couldn't find solution by googling. I have table something like this:

```
recnr event  date
1     event1 today-3
2     event2 today-2
3     event3 today
4     event4 today
5     event5 today+3
6     event6 today+7
```

I have to create query which will select 3 most recent events starting with today. I've tried with:

```
SELECT event FROM table
WHERE (date <= CURDATE()) recnr LIMIT 3;
```

but it selects first three events in the table. How to tell it to start with today and go backwards and not to start with first and go forward?

Comment: Did you try to include an order by? Otherwise the record are ordered by the table index

Comment: There is a manual for this sort of thing

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is: SELECT event FROM table
WHERE (date <= CURDATE()) ORDER BY date, recnr LIMIT 3;

Answer (score 2):

Use an order by statement?

```
SELECT event FROM table WHERE (date <= CURDATE()) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `order by` clause in your query

> Reference -  [order by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

```
SELECT event FROM table WHERE (date <= CURDATE()) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3 ;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write it in query. ORDER by date exists. But such query returns rows started with the oldest date. What I need is to start selection with youngest today and go backwards 3 rows.

Comment: for date we have `desc` which means from higher to lower